# MySQL - After Update Trigger on Specific Column affects all rows in the table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, sql-update

In my database (MySQL) I have the following trigger -

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_qty_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF inventory_sku_quantity ON inventory_sku 
BEGIN 
  UPDATE inventory_sku 
  SET inventory_sku_quantity = 0 
  WHERE NEW.inventory_sku_quantity < 0; 
END;
```

The goal is to make the `inventory_sku_quantity` to zero when it is less than zero. But what we are observing is that when we update an item with the sku quantity less than zero, all the sku quantity is becoming zero.

It appears that the where condition is incorrect - `WHERE NEW.inventory_sku_quantity < 0;` and instead it should be

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_qty_trigger 
AFTER UPDATE OF inventory_sku_quantity 
ON inventory_sku 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE inventory_sku 
    SET inventory_sku_quantity = 0 
    WHERE inventory_id = NEW.inventory_id 
    AND NEW.inventory_sku_quantity < 0; 
END;
```

In summary two questions:

1. Is it allowed to use the `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to reset the affected column value.
2. We have the issue of the trigger makes all the rows `inventory_sku_quantity` to become zero.

Instead I want only the impacted row to be zero and that meant adding an extra condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NEW.inventory_sku_quantity` is the value of the **newly inserted row**. So, your code basically performs the update on every row where the newly inserted row adheres to some condition, which will be all of them, as the content of the row doesn't effect the condition.

Instead of an update, you just need to set the value of the new row in a `before update` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inventory_qty_trigger 
BEFORE UPDATE OF inventory_sku_quantity 
ON inventory_sku 
BEGIN 
    IF NEW.inventory_sku_quantity < 0 THEN
       SET NEW.inventory_sku_quantity = 0
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the if condition.

```
BEGIN 
  if NEW.inventory_sku_quantity < 0 then 
    UPDATE inventory_sku 
    SET inventory_sku_quantity = 0 
    WHERE inventory_id = NEW.inventory_id ; 
  end;
END;
```